# Binary Tree Insert String

Tags: python, data-structures, binary-tree

so here I want to make a case study of a binary tree, namely a file directory, but I'm confused about the section below, how do you do it? I've tried using some logic, but it still doesn't work, can you help?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvVRn.jpg)

````
```
    class Node:
      def __init__(self, data):
        self.right = None
        self.left = None
        self.data = data

      def insert(self,newData):
        if self.data:
          if newData[0] != self.data:
            if self.left is None:
              self.left = Node(newData[1])
            else:
              self.left.insert(newData[1])
  
          elif newData[0] != self.data:
            if self.right is None:
              self.right = Node(newData[1])
            else:
              self.right.insert(newData[1])
      
        else:
          self.data = newData[0]

      def preOrderTraversal(self,root):
        penampung = []
        if root:
          penampung.append(root.data)
          penampung = penampung + self.preOrderTraversal(root.left)
          penampung = penampung + self.preOrderTraversal(root.right)
        return penampung
```

```
    while True:
      menu = int(input("Pilih Menu: "))
      if menu == 1:
        fileRoot = input("Masukan Root: ")
        root = Node(fileRoot)
      elif menu == 2:
        fileChild = input("Masukan Child: ")
        root.insert(fileChild.split())
      elif menu == 3:
        print(root.preOrderTraversal(root))
```
````

Comment: *"I'm confused"* ... *"it still doesn't work"*: this is very vague. Please describe what the program should be doing: in which order should input be given, and what logic should be used to determine where a node should be created. What is the exactly is going wrong, what you have done to debug the problem.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Its Solved

````
```
from os import pipe

    class Node:
      def __init__(self, data):
        self.right = None
        self.left = None
        self.data = data

      def insert(self,newData, parent):
        if self.data == parent:
            if self.left is None:
              self.left = Node(newData)
            else:
              if self.right is None:
                self.right = Node(newData)
  
        elif self.left.data == parent:
          if self.left.left is None:
            self.left.left = Node(newData)
          else:
            if self.left.right is None:
              self.left.right = Node(newData)
  
        elif self.right.data == parent:
          if self.right.left is None:
            self.right.left = Node(newData)
          else:
            if self.right.right is None:
              self.right.right = Node(newData)
        
        else:
          self.data = newData

      def preOrderTraversal(self):
        print(self.data, end=", ")
        if self.left:
          self.left.preOrderTraversal()
        if self.right:
          self.right.preOrderTraversal()
  
```

```
    def main():
      while True:
        menu = int(input("\nPilih Menu: "))
        if menu == 1:
          fileRoot = input("Masukan Root: ")
          root = Node(fileRoot)
        elif menu == 2:
          child = input("Masukan Child ( Target_folder , Nama_folder): ").split()
          parent_folder = child[0]
          child_folder = child[2]
          root.insert(child_folder,parent_folder)
        elif menu == 3:
          root.preOrderTraversal()

    main()
```
````